# Promisified function type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am writing a RFC library. 
Basically I have an interface that is implemented on the server and wrapped by a `Proxy` in the client. The `Proxy` then does http calls in the background to call the method on the server.

This works fine with functions that already return a `Promise`. 
However on the client functions will always return a `Promise` through the `Proxy` wrapper, but the type system does not know this.

So with the following code I am creating a mapped type to change the return types of the functions to `Promise`.

```
// Generic Function definition
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;
// Extracts the type if wrapped by a Promise
type Unpacked<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

type PromisifiedFunction<T extends AnyFunction> =
    T extends () => infer U ? () => Promise<Unpacked<U>> :
    T extends (a1: infer A1) => infer U ? (a1: A1) => Promise<Unpacked<U>> :
    T extends (a1: infer A1, a2: infer A2) => infer U ? (a1: A1, a2: A2) => Promise<Unpacked<U>> :
    T extends (a1: infer A1, a2: infer A2, a3: infer A3) => infer U ? (a1: A1, a2: A2, a3: A3) => Promise<Unpacked<U>> :
    // ...
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? (...args: any[]) => Promise<Unpacked<U>> : T;

type Promisified<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction ? PromisifiedFunction<T[K]> : never
}
```

**Example:**

```
interface HelloService {
    /**
    * Greets the given name
    * @param name 
    */
    greet(name: string): string;
}

function createRemoteService<T>(): Promisified<T> { /*...*/ }

const hello = createRemoteService<HelloService>();
// typeof hello = Promisified<HelloService>
hello.greet("world").then(str => { /*...*/ }) // all fine here
// typeof hello.greet = (a1: string) => Promise<string>
```

Well everything works, so whats the problem?

What I do not like about this implementation is, that argument names and documentation gets lost (at least in vs code).

[image]

So for the person that just wants to consume a service it is not a nice development experience to look up the service definition somewhere external.

The other thing I do not like is that I have to write a definition for every amount of arguments. But I guess there is no other way until Typescript supports [Variadic Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453).

**EDIT:** While continue working with this I discovered a bigger problem:
Having an overloaded function in the interface the mapped interface is not correctly inferred.

```
interface HelloService {
    greet(name: string): string;
    greet(id: number): string;
}
```

Depending on the order of the functions the mapped type is either 
`typeof hello.greet = (a1: string) => Promise<string>` or 
`typeof hello.greet = (a1: number) => Promise<string>`

But it is supposed to be: 
`typeof hello.greet = (a1: string|number) => Promise<string>`

So any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: Nope, 99.9% sure there is no way to improve on this, you will lose function names. Unfortunately there are no mapped functions

Comment: @AluanHaddad reversing the order will result in additional required arguments: 
`typeof hello.greet = (a1: string, a2: {}, a3: {} ...) => Promise<string>`

Comment: I see. I was reading it wrong. Still not used to the ternary in that position and missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new Typescript 3.0 one can use [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters).

This allows us to specify the types like this:

```
type UnpackPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

type AnyFunction<U extends any[], V> = (...args: U) => V;
type Promisified<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction<infer U, infer V> ? (...args: U) => Promise<UnpackPromise<V>> : never;
}
```